# Tuple indexing and printing

Tags: python, list, printing, tuples

Python beginner here and a little confused with tuples when working with them as lists. I have the code below and to my understanding the peek function should return the first tuple pair but in reality it returns only the first word of that pair. Why is this??

Thanks in advance everyone.

```
tuples = [('big', 'apple'), ('small', 'orange'), ('medium', 'berry')]

def peek(word_list):
    if word_list:
        word = word_list[0]
        return word[0]
    else:
        return None




peek(tuples) #prints big

print tuples[0] #prints ('big', 'apple')
```

Comment: actually your `peek` function does not `return` anything because there is no `return` statement in the `if` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
word = word_list[0]      # first tuple
print word[0]            # first entry of the first tuple
```

You've got two `[0]` dereferences. This code is equivalent to

```
print word_list[0][0]    # first entry of the first tuple
```

Get rid of one of them.

```
word = word_list[0]      # first tuple
print word               # first tuple
```

Comment: Makes total sense! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and see:

```
word_list = [('big', 'apple'), ('small', 'orange'), ('medium', 'berry')]
word = word_list[0]
print(word)
print(word[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

In peek function, replace

```
print word[0]
```

with

```
print word
```

Since word[0] is actually word_list[0][0] which is 1st element in 1st tuple, i.e. "big". In short, think of "tuples" as a 2*3 array.